# My custom font doesn't want to work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm trying to use the Green Pillow and Cotidiana fonts on a site I'm working on. I've loaded the .eot file using @font-face but it's still not working...

Really not sure what I've done wrong here:

```
@font-face {  
 font-family: "link_font";  
 src: url( "Greenpiloww.eot" ); /* IE */  
 src: local("GreenPillow"), url( "GREENPIL.otf" ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}  


@font-face {  
font-family: "twitter_font";  
 src: url( "Cotidiana.eot" ); /* IE */  
src: local("Cotidiana"), url( "Cotidiana.ttf" ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}
```

Comment: ***sigh*** ... If only I had a $$$ for every time I said to myself, *"Gee whiz, this works in every browser but Internet Explorer."*

Comment: Have you heard of cufon? Might be worth a look at: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: Well that should work, what did you use to convert the fonts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might try the following syntax, known as the [bulletproof font-face syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

Apparently the querystring after the `.eot` font helps IE not choke. If you don't have .svg or .woff versions of your fonts, just remove those lines.

Comment: Thanks very much, this solves the issue. Annoying that microsoft's font rendering is so bad but ah well.

Comment: I already had the code described in this answer, however in IE it still appeared to not be working. I discovered that a combination of F5-ing and loading a different page is what IE needs to get its act together.