# Custom fonts not working in ie 8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face, custom-font

My custom fonts aren't rendering in ie8.
I've allready tried clearing the cache, and I'm also sending the correct filetypes if I'm not mistaken.
What am I missing here?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Lobster';
src: url('fonts/lobster.eot');
src: url('fonts/lobster.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/lobster.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/lobster.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/lobster.svg#Lobster1.4Regular') format('svg');
}

.logoHome{color:#FFF; font: 58px Lobster, serif; text-decoration:none; line-height:58px;}
```

Comment: This question has an IE fix, maybe that helps? [My custom font doesn't want to work in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8931224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line gave an error.
Removing:

```
src: url('fonts/lobster.eot');
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

the problem it is easy solve, just make the url path to be relative:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    src: url('http://www.sample.com/fonts/lobster.eot');
    src: url('http://www.sample.com/fonts/lobster.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.sample.com/fonts/lobster.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.sample.com/fonts/lobster.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.sample.com/fonts/lobster.svg#Lobster13Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

but this will only work down to ***IE8*** you can use this [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) to always check which thing you can use in older browsers

Comment: also the entire path ro the file? which IE are you testing? it will **not** work on IE 7

Comment: if not i create a package, i tested and worked perfect in IE 8 to 10 and all major browsers... 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19706494/Lobster.zip

Comment: On test I did put the entire path in front, but I removed it since it seemed to have no function.
Removed "src: url('fonts/lobster.eot');" in my original file, now it works in all IE.