# How get custom fonts to display in IE?

Tags: css, fonts

I've made a custom font of icons (by loading up SVG files), and am trying to get it to display in IE. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but the fonts are invisible in IE, from IE8 to IE11 (and presumably earlier)... The letter "d" for example displays instead. I've generated the fonts through Fontello and Fontastic, and both have the same problem.

My CSS is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "triangle";
src:url("untitled-font-1.eot");
src:url("untitled-font-1.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff"),
url("untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg");
}

h2{
color:#000000;
}

h2:before{
content:"d";
font-family:triangle;
font-size:16px;
color:#000000;
}
```

How on earth do I get them to display?!

Comment: Your font-face is missing a closing tag. Is this intentional?

Comment: Nope - sorry - that's my writing on here - css file is fine...

Comment: Have you tried adding a font-weight and type to it just to make sure it pulls the correct one?

Comment: @JohnG have you tried my suggestion ? I had same problem in IE.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi!**

I had the same issue and solved it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931224/my-custom-font-doesnt-want-to-work-in-internet-explorer).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

The query after .eot makes IE not to fail reading the lines and if there are any font-formats that is not being used make sure to remove them.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work for lots of people, but not for me unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the true type font works, then go to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, upload the font and follow the instructions to get css code and font files.