# using @font-face in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, microsoft-edge

I am dealing with a strange issue here.. It seems that Microsoft Edge browser doesn't load fonts when I use @font-face. I checked all my computers that run Windows 10 & Microsoft Edge.

I checked http://caniuse.com/#search=font%20face

It says that font-face is compatible with Edge so I don't know what's going on.
In my example I just have a div and its font parameter.

**CSS**

```
@font-face{font-family:'Dosis';font-style:normal;font-weight:200;src:local('Dosis ExtraLight'), local('Dosis-ExtraLight'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v4/RPKDmaFi75RJkvjWaDDb0vesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');}
@font-face{font-family:'Dosis';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Dosis Bold'), local('Dosis-Bold'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v4/22aDRG5X9l7obljtz7tihvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');}
```

**HTML**

```
div {
  font-family:'Dosis';
}
```

**Live version**

http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/YwGGWy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931224/my-custom-font-doesnt-want-to-work-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Procedure:**

The procedure I followed in order to install all necessary formats was to find which font-weight I needed from each font and then go and download it from Google Fonts. Then using the https://everythingfonts.com/font-face (font face generator) I downloaded all the formats along with the CSS code. Then I incorporated them all into my CSS and HTML.

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JosefinSansLight';
    src: url('/fonts/JosefinSansLight.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/JosefinSansLight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/JosefinSansLight.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/JosefinSansLight.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/JosefinSansLight.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**HTML (excerpt):**

```
.testim{
font-family:'JosefinSansLight', sans-serif;
line-height:normal;
color:#969696;
font-size:1.2em;
}
```

**Files: (my domain folder)/fonts**

```
fonts/JosefinSansLight.eot
fonts/JosefinSansLight.eot
fonts/JosefinSansLight.woff2
fonts/JosefinSansLight.woff
fonts/JosefinSansLight.ttf
```

Comment: This does not provide anything in addition to the answer that was already here

Comment: The link for converting font-face and the procedure wasn't in the provided answer!!

Answer (score 6):

You are using only `WOFF2` format which has no support on Microsoft Edge.

[WOFF2 Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2)

To solve the problem include `WOFF` format in your `@font-face` declaration. Most of the modern browser [supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) `WOFF`

For maximum browser support include all possible format.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot');
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I know this but the thing is that I don't have access to the links for the woff format.. This is why I posted a new question about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453010/finding-all-other-formats-for-a-google-font-beside-woff2

Comment: @justme That has nothing to do with programming, but rather having necessary files. This is the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

I just found that if you have the google font installed locally (eg if you've been doing a mockup), edge will not display the web font version.  I did a lot of reading round to find the root of the issue and did not see anyone mention this.

hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed for Microsoft Edge regarding .woff fonts. I recently purchased a Windows 10 laptop. The websites that had .woff fonts in @font-face did not display them in Microsoft Edge but did display them in Internet Explorer. The [Microsoft developer website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bg124110%28v=vs.85%29) as of 5/11/2016 says that .woff2 is supported in Edge as follows.

*Microsoft Edge supports the Web Open Font Format (WOFF) File Format 2.0 specification which provides an improved compression algorithm from WOFF 1.0. The font format "woff2" is supported.*

Here is an example of the CSS code I implemented in all of my websites to successfully display my special fonts using Microsoft Edge based on the link above.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Eurostile;
  src: url("http://mylink/eurostile.woff"), url("http://mylink/eurostile.woff2"), url("http://mylink/eurostile.eot"), url("http://mylink/eurostile.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12315755)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanArgentiero. I have updated my answer. If any more changes need to be made please let me know.