# finding all other formats for a Google font beside "woff2"

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, microsoft-edge, woff

In a previous question of mine it was pointed out to me that "**woff2**" format doesn't work on **Microsoft Edge**. So I have to use an alternative syntax of @font-face if I want my website to look good in Microsoft Edge.

**Original CSS**

```
@font-face{font-family:'Dosis';font-style:normal;font-weight:200;src:local('Dosis ExtraLight'), local('Dosis-ExtraLight'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v4/RPKDmaFi75RJkvjWaDDb0vesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');}
@font-face{font-family:'Dosis';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Dosis Bold'), local('Dosis-Bold'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dosis/v4/22aDRG5X9l7obljtz7tihvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');}
```

**Suggested CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

So what I am trying to do is to find all other formats (truetype, woff etc) for 'Dosis' for example..

I used : http://webfonts.azurewebsites.net/?fontname=Dosis
It gives me only the 400 weight version of Dosis.

Do you know other ways so I can have the correct versions of Dosis in the necessary formats?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use google font following way

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Change the font weight according to your choose like `href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200'`

In that case you need not to worry about  different format. just use `font-family:'Dosis';` in your style.

Comment: I know this and I could also use @import too but these are something that I would like not to use.