# Fonts not showing up in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm creating a WordPress template, using @font-face to get fonts. The fonts show up fine on Chrome and Firefox. However, when I go to Microsoft Edge, the font doesn't show up...

You can see the issue here:
http://www.tbsmb.school/home/
The font is ClaireHand and appears in the top menu ("About, Admissions, Programs, Support...")

Below is the font-face style code...

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ClaireHand';
  src: url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.eot');
  src: url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  
  url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.otf')  format('opentype'),
  url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
  url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.svg#ClaireHand') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

I know the fonts path are correct, because they work in other browsers.

I've looked around Stackoverflow, and while people had font issues, none answered my questions.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried including a woff2, instead of just plain woff? [caniuse says](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) regular woff is supported, but the Microsoft Developer Network site [leaves it kinda ambiguous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg124110(v=vs.85).aspx), only mentioning support for woff2. I noticed that as a possible explanation from the last answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452288/using-font-face-in-microsoft-edge). (caniuse also says other types are supported, so still kinda fishy, but maybe worth a shot.)

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thought woff was fine ... guess it wasn't. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, good deal. I will post that as an answer then, so this question can be closed out.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has to support the font you are giving it.

If the font isn't working on a single browser but fine on others, it's likely because Edge doesn't support that type of font.

Use a safe-font for default if the browser can't handle the fonts you are trying to give it.

Using CSS you can do it this way:
font-family: coolfont, maybe-another-cool-font, safefont

It will try coolfont first, then 'maybe-another...' until the final font which should be a font chosen safe for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in [a newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452288/using-font-face-in-microsoft-edge#37160939) to a similar, old question, Microsoft seem to only support WOFF2 fonts in Edge these days, not regular WOFF.

From the Microsoft Developer Network:

> Microsoft Edge supports the Web Open Font Format (WOFF) File Format 2.0 specification which provides an improved compression algorithm from WOFF 1.0. The font format `"woff2"` is supported.

So adding WOFF2 to your `@font-face` rule should do the trick:

`url('<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/ClaireHand.woff2') format('woff2')`